# hsky_ur5_moveit gazebo inertial not stable

Tags: ros, husky, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am simulating husky_ur5_moveit package http://wiki.ros.org/husky_ur5_moveit_config in ROS indigo.Bt its inertial parameters are not stable

It appears as following

http://i65.tinypic.com/25036u8.png

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220411/hsky_ur5_moveit-gazebo-inertial-not-stable/) by [telephus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21609/telephus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-01**:
Can you please upload the screenshot to ROS Answers itself? You should have enough karma now to do that. If the `tinypic` one ever disappears, there'll be no way to understand this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Set laser_enabled to false.

Best,

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2018-04-23**:
What if you need to use the laser with ur5 altogether, then you need to figure out the inertial problem?